# install i2c library on python

Tags: python-3.x, i2c

I'm doing a school project to read the temperature through the sensor mlx90615.
In my code an error appears:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/p/12345.py", line 21, in 
   Import i2c
Importerror: no module named 'i2c'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    It clearly indicates that the required jar files are missing 
http://pyi2c.sourceforge.net/ You can download from here and add the jar file in your referencing environment. That will help to overcome the error.
```

Answer (score 0):

I already did it but it continues with the same error